# how to send multiple value in database by checking multiple checkbox in php

Tags: php, mysql

Here I have a form where I'm having checkboxes and a textarea field.

Now the number of checkboxes are getting fetched from database. How I want to insert values in database of the checkboxes that I will check and the corresponding textarea fields value.

But when I click on submit button proper data is not getting inserted. Can anyone help?

```
<?php

$sql_course="select * from lk_tb_course ";
$query_course=mysql_query($sql_course);
while($row_course=mysql_fetch_array($query_course))
{
?>

<input type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $row_course['course_id']; ?>" name="courses_id[]" class="" ><?php echo " ".$row_course["course_name"]; ?>
<textarea name="admission_criteria[]"></textarea>

<?php }  ?>

<input type="submit" value="save" name="save"/>
</form>
```

Here is my PHP code:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST["save"]))
{
    for($i=0;$i<count($_POST["courses_id"]); $i++)
    {    
        $courses_id=$_POST["courses_id"][$i];
        $admission_criteria=$_POST["admission_criteria"][$i];
        mysql_query("insert into tb_college_course set course_id='$courses_id',admission_criteria='$admission_criteria'");
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: is `$courses_id` a integer or string?

Comment: $course_id is interger

Comment: then you should treat it that way not `course_id='$courses_id', ...` right is `course_id=$courses_id, ...`. And, has yor table only 2 fields ?

Comment: i did not got your point and yes my database has only 2 fields

Comment: you treat with `course_id='...'` as a string. If `course_id` is UNIQUE then you need to test in advance whether this `data set` does not already exist.

Comment: look i have checkboxes and a textarea with each checkbox..now i want to insert the values of the checkboxes checked and their corresponding textareas value but when i am inserting then only checkbox values are getting inserted and not the corresponding textarea's values

Comment: Can you please show us your `<form action ...>`  tag ??

Comment: have you seen my answer ?

Answer (score 0):

- Use mysql_* no longer. which is deprecated. if you are in the beginning a new development,  you should not use an outdated database solution.
- If you have problems with handover from a html form to the evaluating program, then let the whole database stuff away. People think it is up to the database and not on parsing a post-handover and put their attention on the database part.

[mysqli-connect](http://php.net/manual/de/function.mysqli-connect.php)
[pdo.construct](http://php.net/manual/de/pdo.construct.php)

---

To your question:

This is based on a fallacy.

We assume in the html form  6 checkboxes, 6 textareas
and data table has also 6 records ID's are 2,10,150,200,201,202

checkbox[0] not checked
checkbox[1] not checked
checkbox[2] not checked
...
checkbox[3] checked
checkbox[4] checked
checkbox[5] checked

via post we get 3 checkboxes and 6 Textareas !!!

checkbox from [3] to [5]
Textarea from [0] to [5]

count checkboxes `count($_POST["courses_id"]` is 3

with `for($i=0;$i<count($_POST["courses_id"]); $i++)` we get

$i = 0 to 2 values from

checkbox[0]   not isset
checkbox[1]   not isset
checkbox[2]   not isset

To get to each other now associated values, you do the following (from 0 to 2).

ID =  checkbox[$i]  ==  checkbox[0] (must be checkbox[3])
text = textarea[$i] ==  textarea[0] ( textarea[3] )

checkbox[0]  **is not valid** it is not avialable   normally error
textarea[0]  is set but empty = ""

Best is you set the current ID.
So you always have really existing values ​​from your data table.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="courses_id[$row_course['course_id']]"    
<textarea name="admission_criteria[$row_course['course_id']]"
```

Otherwise, the assignment is no longer true to your table

```
 <?php
 $CourseID = $row_course['course_id'];
 echo "<input type=\"checkbox\" value=\"".$CourseID."\""; 
 echo " name=\"courses_id[".$CourseID."]\" class=\"\" >";
 echo " ".$row_course["course_name"]."<br />\n"; 
 echo " <textarea name=\"admission_criteria[".$CourseID."]\"></textarea><br />\n";
 ?>
```

---

use foreach

```
$coursesArr=$_POST["courses_id"];

foreach ($coursesArr as $key => $IDvalue) {
     echo $key."<br />\n";
     $admission_criteria=$_POST["admission_criteria"][$key]; 
     echo $admission_criteria."<br />\n";
 }
```